# How can I make Exoplayer2 run in background? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I am a noob in Kotlin.
I've made a streaming music player using Exoplayer2.
For running this music player in background, I tried to bind activity to service.
But it is not working.

I dont know why this player is stopped outside the app even though i add the foreground service.

Can anybody help me? :(

MusicService.kt

```
var mExoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

class MusicService : MediaBrowserServiceCompat() {
    private var mMediaSession: MediaSessionCompat? = null
    private lateinit var mStateBuilder: PlaybackStateCompat.Builder
    private var playbackPosition = 0L
    private var currentWindow = 0
    private var oldUri: Uri? = null


private val mMediaSessionCallback = object : MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
    override fun onPlayFromUri(uri: Uri?, extras: Bundle?) {
        super.onPlayFromUri(uri, extras)
        uri?.let {
            val mediaSource = extractMediaSourceFromUri(uri)
            if (uri != oldUri)
                play(mediaSource)
            else play()
            oldUri = uri
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        pause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        stop()
    }
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    initializePlayer()
    initializeExtractor()
    initializeAttributes()

    mMediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(baseContext, "tag for debugging").apply {

        setFlags(
            MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS or
                    MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS            )

        mStateBuilder = PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)
        setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build())

        setCallback(mMediaSessionCallback)

        setSessionToken(sessionToken)
        isActive = true
    }
}

private var mAttrs: AudioAttributes? = null

private fun play(mediaSource: MediaSource) {
    if (mExoPlayer == null) initializePlayer()
    mExoPlayer?.apply {
        mAttrs?.let { initializeAttributes() }
        mAttrs?.let { setAudioAttributes(it, true) }
        prepare(mediaSource)
        seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
        playWhenReady = true
    }
}

private fun play() {
    mExoPlayer?.apply {
        mExoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
        updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING)
        mMediaSession?.isActive = true
    }
}

private fun initializePlayer() {
    mExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
        this, DefaultRenderersFactory(baseContext)
        , DefaultTrackSelector(),
        DefaultLoadControl()
    )
}


private fun pause() {
    mExoPlayer?.apply {
        playWhenReady = false
        if (playbackState == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
            updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED)
        }
    }
}

private fun stop() {
    mExoPlayer?.playWhenReady = false
    mExoPlayer?.release()
    mExoPlayer = null
    updatePlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_NONE)
    mMediaSession?.isActive = false
    mMediaSession?.release()
}

override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    stopSelf()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    stop()
}

private fun updatePlaybackState(state: Int) {
    mMediaSession?.setPlaybackState(
        PlaybackStateCompat.Builder().setState(
            state
            , 0L
            , 1.0f // Speed playing
        ).build()
    )
}

private fun initializeAttributes() {
    mAttrs = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build()
}

private lateinit var mExtractorFactory: ExtractorMediaSource.Factory

private fun initializeExtractor() {
    val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(baseContext, "Application Name")
    mExtractorFactory = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent))
        .setExtractorsFactory(DefaultExtractorsFactory())
}

private fun extractMediaSourceFromUri(uri: Uri): MediaSource {

    return mExtractorFactory.createMediaSource(uri)
}

override fun onLoadChildren(parentId: String, result: Result<MutableList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>) {

}

override fun onGetRoot(clientPackageName: String, clientUid: Int, rootHints: Bundle?): BrowserRoot? {
    return BrowserRoot("", null)
}
```

playerAct.kt

```
var audioUrlPass = ""

class playerAct: AppCompatActivity() { private val songUrl: String = audioUrlPass


private lateinit var mMediaBrowserCompat: MediaBrowserCompat

private val connectionCallback: MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback = object : MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {
    override fun onConnected() {
        super.onConnected()
        mMediaBrowserCompat.sessionToken.also { token ->
            val mediaController = MediaControllerCompat(this@playerAct, token)
            MediaControllerCompat.setMediaController(this@playerAct, mediaController)
        }
        playPauseBuild()
    }
    override fun onConnectionFailed() {
        super.onConnectionFailed()
    }
}

private val mControllerCallback = object : MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {
}

fun playPauseBuild() {
    val mediaController = MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(this@playerAct)
    main_pcv.showTimeoutMs = 0
    exo_play.setOnClickListener {
        val state = mediaController.playbackState.state

        if (state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED ||
            state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED ||
            state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_NONE
        ) {

            mediaController.transportControls.playFromUri(Uri.parse(songUrl), null)

        }

        else if (state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING ||
            state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_BUFFERING ||
            state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_CONNECTING
        ) {
            mediaController.transportControls.pause()

        }
    }
    mediaController.registerCallback(mControllerCallback)

}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.player_layout)
    val componentName = ComponentName(this, MusicService::class.java)

    mMediaBrowserCompat = MediaBrowserCompat(
        this, componentName, //Identifier for the service
        connectionCallback,
        null
    )
    menuButton.setOnClickListener {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

    btnTime1.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, TimerActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    playerSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
        object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

            override fun onProgressChanged(seekbar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                if (fromUser){
                    val volumeNum = progress / 100.0f
                    mExoPlayer!!.setVolume(volumeNum)
                }
            }
            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekbar: SeekBar?) { }
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekbar: SeekBar?) { }
        })

}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()controller
    Intent(this, MusicService::class.java).also {
        mMediaBrowserCompat.connect()
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    val controllerCompat = MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(this)
    controllerCompat?.unregisterCallback(mControllerCallback)
    mMediaBrowserCompat.disconnect()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to start the foreground service, you will need a notification shown within 5 seconds of starting it. Check the following guide in **the android documentation:** https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#mediastyle-notifications